# How can I implement an optimal, purely functional, double-ended priority queue?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming, persistence, priority-queue

Okasaki shows how to write purely functional priority queues with `O(1)` `insert` and `O(log n)` `minView` (some versions also offer `O(log n)` or even `O(1)` `merge`. Can any of these ideas be extended to *double-ended* priority queues? Khoong and Leong (in a paper I don't have access to) offer an ephemeral implementation based on binomial heaps, but from what I can see of their paper, that approach doesn't seem easy to make persistent, as it uses parent and sibling pointers.

Comment: Do you need something _provably optimal_, or just _good in practice_? Because surely a finger tree will work just fine for this.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, ooh, that's interesting. Should've thought of that myself! I imagine that will work. `Data.PriorityQueue.FingerTree` claims `O(log n)` for `insert`, but it sure *looks* `O(1)`. I wonder if that's a documentation bug.

Comment: I think that's a worst-case vs amortized issue. Which turns out to matter a lot with persistent data structures, so it's worth paying attention to.

Comment: @Carl, it always matters, but for finger trees the (persistently!) amortized constant time operations are also worst-case logarithmic (under very mildly restricted conditions), so it probably doesn't matter terribly *much*. That said, I'd certainly be interested in a more efficient option!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_Genesis. also, googling "Khoong and Leong" gives  https://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/papers/ianfest13.pdf

Answer (score 2):

As leftaroundabout points out, this can be done with a 2–3 finger tree. In particular, one annotated with the semigroup

```
data MinMax k = MinMax
  { smallest :: !k
  , largest :: !k }

instance Ord k => Semigroup (MinMax k) where
  MinMax min1 max1 <> MinMax min2 max2 = MinMax (min min1 min2) (max max1 max2)
```

Such an annotated finger tree can be made a double-ended priority queue in basically the same way that the `fingertree` package defines priority queues (but adjusted slightly to avoid needing a `Monoid`). `minView` and `maxView` can be improved using the same implementation technique as `Data.Sequence.deleteAt`.

Why use a `Semigroup` and not add a neutral element to make it a `Monoid`? This way, we can unpack `MinMax` annotations into tree nodes and avoid an extra indirection at every step, along with extra allocation.

Performance bounds

- `insert`: Amortized O(1) (note: this bound will hold up even in the face of persistence, thanks to careful use of laziness). Worst-case O(log n). Note that the `fingertree` package only claims O(log n) for insertion; this is a documentation bug which I have reported and which will be corrected in the next version.
- `minView`/`maxView`: Worst-case O(1) to see the minimum/maximum; worst-case O(log n) to remove it.
- `meld`: Worst-case O(log (min (m, n)), where `m` and `n` are the sizes of the queues.

---

Hinze-Paterson style 2–3 finger trees are actually a bit more than necessary. A one-fingered version will do the trick, with fewer digit sizes.

```
{-# options_ghc -funbox-strict-fields #-}

data Node k a
  = Node2 !(MinMax k) !a !a
  | Node3 !(MinMax k) !a !a !a

data Tree k a
  = Empty
    -- the child of a Zero node may
    -- not be empty
  | Zero !(MinMax k) (Tree k (Node k a))
  | One !(MinMax k) !a (Tree k (Node k a))
```

I've been working on fleshing this out for the last few days. Fortunately, it's mostly quite straightforward. Unfortunately, it requires an awful lot of code. The fundamental challenge is that deletion in 2–3 trees is fairly involved. The version for finger trees adds another layer of complexity. And then the whole thing has to be written twice to deal with both `minView` and `maxView`.